# License Upgrade - Windows 8 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: windows-8

I want to upgrade my computer to Windows 8 pro 64 bit. I currently have Windows 8 Pro 32 bit. I'm fine with re-installing. What I want to know is what is the cheapest process to do this?

I tried running the Windows 8 Upgrade Advisor and it said that it was not available in my country. I'm in the US. My guess is that it isn't designed for people already running Windows 8.

Comment: Did the PC come with Win8 pre-installed?

Comment: It came with Vista. I upgraded to Windows 8 using Upgrade Advisor and installed that on a new SSD.

Comment: Yep, as you noted you can easily run the Upgrade Assistant on a 64-bit PC, create the setup media and use that instead. If the PC had come with Win8 32-bit pre-installed, while the key embedded in the BIOS should work with the 64-bit version, the problem would have been laying your hands on the appropriate setup media.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I can use my existing license.  I'll need to use a bootable USB drive or another computer (that is 64bit) and download Windows 8.

[Download Windows 8](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=262204)

Comment: Correct. Microsoft does not make 32-bit and 64-bit keys; Windows keys work for both versions.

Comment: It also looks like I can get a backup copy from Microsoft for $15 that includes both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: The only thing to remember here is that you still only have one license. You don't get to install 32-bit on one machine and 64-bit on another.